# Chainging the hypergeometric series $F(\alpha,\beta,\gamma;z)$ to an integral form

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, gamma-function, beta-function

This is problem 6.9 in Stein complex analysis.

> Let
> $$F(\alpha,\beta,\gamma;z) = 1+\sum_{n=1}^\infty{\alpha(\alpha+1)\cdots(\alpha+n-1)\beta(\beta+1)\cdots(\beta+n-1)\over n!\gamma(\gamma+1)\cdots(\gamma+n-1)}z^n$$
> be the hypergeometric series for $\alpha,\beta\in\Bbb C$ and $\gamma\neq 0,-1,-2,\cdots$. Note that the ratio test implies this series has the radius of convergence $1$.
> For $\alpha>0,\beta>0,\gamma>\beta$ and $|z|<1$, show that
> $$F(\alpha,\beta,\gamma;z) = {\Gamma(\gamma)\over\Gamma(\beta)\Gamma(\gamma-\beta)}\int_0^1 t^{\beta-1}(1-t)^{\gamma-\beta-1}(1-zt)^{-\alpha}\ dt.$$
> [Hint: To prove the integral identity, expand $(1-zt)^{-\alpha}$ as a power series.]

My attempt: Direct computation shows that the Taylor expansion of $(1-zt)^{-\alpha}$ at $z =0$ is
$$(1-zt)^{-\alpha} = 1+\sum_{n=1}^\infty{\alpha(\alpha+1)\cdots(\alpha+n-1)t^n\over n!}z^n.$$
Since $\Gamma$ function has no zero, it suffices to show
$${\Gamma(\beta)\Gamma(\gamma-\beta)\over\Gamma(\gamma)}F(\alpha,\beta,\gamma;z) =\int_0^1 t^{\beta-1}(1-t)^{\gamma-\beta-1}(1-zt)^{-\alpha}\ dt.\tag{$\dagger$}$$
Note that
$${\Gamma(\beta)\Gamma(\gamma-\beta)\over\Gamma(\gamma)} = B(\beta,\gamma-\beta) = \int_0^1 t^{\beta-1}(1-t)^{\gamma-\beta-1}\ dt,$$
where $B$ is a beta function.

Then the LHS of $(\dagger)$ becomes
$$\int_0^1 t^{\beta-1}(1-t)^{\gamma-\beta-1}\ dt+\sum_{n=1}^\infty{\alpha(\alpha+1)\cdots(\alpha+n-1)\beta(\beta+1)\cdots(\beta+n-1)\over n!\gamma(\gamma+1)\cdots(\gamma+n-1)}z^n\int_0^1 t^{\beta-1}(1-t)^{\gamma-\beta-1}\ dt$$

The RHS of $(\dagger)$ equals
$$\int_0^1 t^{\beta-1}(1-t)^{\gamma-\beta-1}\ dt+\sum_{n=1}^\infty{\alpha(\alpha+1)\cdots(\alpha+n-1)\over n!}z^n\int_0^1 t^{\beta+n-1}(1-t)^{\gamma-\beta-1}\ dt.$$
where the infinite sum can escape the integral by the uniform convergence for $|z|<1$.
To remove $n$ in the integrand, tried integration by parts with $t^{\beta+n-1}$ and $(1-t)^{\gamma-\beta-1}$ but $n$ on $t$ moves to $(1-t)$ so $n$ does not disappear. I'm stuck at this point. Please help.

Comment: Interchange summation an integration, group $t^n$ and $z^n$ like $(zt)^n$ and recognise the binomial expansion for $(1-zt)^{-\alpha}-1$.

Comment: @Gary How does that help?

Comment: Sorry you like to go the other way. Then just note that $$
\int_0^1 {t^{\beta  + n - 1} (1 - t)^{\gamma  - \beta  - 1} dt}  = \frac{{\Gamma (\beta  + n)\Gamma (\gamma  - \beta )}}{{\Gamma (\gamma  + n)}} = \frac{{\Gamma (\beta )\Gamma (\gamma  - \beta )}}{{\Gamma (\gamma )}}\frac{{\beta (\beta  + 1) \ldots (\beta  + n - 1)}}{{\gamma (\gamma  + 1) \ldots (\gamma  + n - 1)}}.
$$ Don't tuch the LHS of $(\dagger)$ though, you only need to do anything with its RHS.

Comment: @Gary Ohh thank you